# Is there an integer type that will role back to −2,147,483,648 if it overflows?

Tags: c#

I'm implementing a tree of objects. Every class within this tree has some properties and a GetHashCode() method. What I plan to do is combine the hashes of all of the properties and then combine that hash with the hashes of the child nodes. I'm not in front of Visual Studio at the moment but the code would look something like this:

```
class Node
{
  public int Prop1 {get; set;}
  public string Prop2 {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<Node> Children {get; set; }
  private int _hash;
  public override int GetHashCode()
  {   
      if (_hash == 0)
      {
        _hash = 17;
        _hash = _hash * 31 + Prop1.GetHashCode();
        _hash = _hash * 31 + Prop2.GetHashCode();
        foreach(var child in Children)
        {
            _hash = _hash * 31 + child.GetHasCode();
        }
      }
      return _hash;
  }
}
```

This should work wbut I'm concerned about ending up with such a large value that I overflow the int 32 type. Is there a different type which would prevent this but I can still return as an int? I've thought of using modulus and uint but how would I then turn this back in to a valid int? Could I just do something like this:

```
unit _hash = 0;
public override int GetHashCode()
{
   // See code above
   return (int)((_hash % 4294967295) - int.MaxValue);
}
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It's a hash function, why not just let it roll around?

Comment: If you don't want rolling action, you could just use a `uint`/`ushort`.

Comment: I thought int types in .NET overflow like this by default?

Comment: I'm confused... do you WANT it to roll around or not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but `unchecked` and `checked` keywords seem like they will be of interest (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx)

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined in C. I can't find anything saying one way or another about its behavior in C#.

Comment: @CoryNelson in [11.1.5 Integral Types](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf), "in an unchecked context, overflows are ignored and any high-order bits that do not fit in the destination type are discarded" (other pieces of the standard imply that negative integers are 2's complement negatives, though it doesn't come right out and say so)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surround you code with [`unchecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) to suppress overflow-checking for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{  
  unchecked
  { 
      if (_hash == 0)
      {
        _hash = 17;
        _hash = _hash * 31 + Prop1.GetHashCode();
        _hash = _hash * 31 + Prop2.GetHashCode();
        foreach(var child in Children)
        {
            _hash = _hash * 31 + child.GetHasCode();
        }
      }
      return _hash;
  }
}
```

Comment: `unchecked` is the default behaviour is c# though... its actually redundant.

Comment: Thanks. Just tested it and int.MaxValue + 1 == int.MinValue

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Magnus awnser, you can also enable/disable arithmetic overflow checks in the project properties under Build > Advanced